# Envolve IM Changes Website Layout

Tags: html

I'm using a facebook like chat called envolve for my site. It works great, except that it changes the some layout properties of my site, specifically the size of some font and links, and the font background in pre tags that are embedded in a custom "lesson" class ()

I was on their site where i asked about it and a couple other people mentioned they have some similar problems but didn't know how to fix it. I contacted their support and after about a week they sent me an email about how they don't have enough resources to look further into the problem, which is understandable since i can't even figure it out ;)

I'm just asking here in case someone might have an answer to this.

To see how the background of the font inside pre tags change when the chat is enabled, go here:
http://braynzarsoft.net/index.php?p=D3D11OBJMODEL

You will have to log in to enable the chat and see the change. Log in with:

```
username: guest
password: pass
```

First look at the page without being logged in, then look at it logged in to see the difference. I'm really out of ideas, so i hope someone here might be able to shed some light on this

EDIT: i should mention to enable envolve on my site, i only need a single line in php, which connects to the envolve server, so there's really not much i can do with the files they provide to enable the service. There's one file that comes with it, called envolve_api_client.php, but all this file does is connect to their server

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

- Make sure all your styling is in stylesheet(s).
- Remove your stylesheet.
- Confirm that their part looks ok.
- Start adding yuor styles back in, one by one (or in groups) and seeing what conflicts.
- Decide what you want to keep and what you want to add.